Caculate the base/ emitter current of PNP transistor
Excuse me, I'm having trouble with my Semiconductor-Experiment Exercise. The transistor code (if necessary) is A1015.

Here is the question: Instead of connecting load (Resistor & LED) to Collector of PNP, we connect it to Emitter like the image above. Can the transistor reach saturation mode?
I just have some basic ideas, the transistor can reach saturation mode if the V_ce is low enough (for below 1V) and the Vce = Vcc-Vdiode-Ic*R1
So, can you figure out how to caculate the Vce and the Base current?
Thank you so much.

"Vce = Vcc-Vdiode-Ic*R1" assumes that the transistor has infinite gain and the base current is zero. So you need a better equation.

@Finbarr thank you very much, but can you give me a hint for the equation please?

Collector current = base current + emitter current

@Finbarr So it will be: ie = ic + ib = ic + Vb/10k right. And is Vb = 0.7V sir

Sorry, it's PNP so emitter current = base current + collector current. And 0.7V is the voltage between emitter and base, not the actual voltage on the base.

(Note: with the arrow on the base pointing that way the base current will be negative)

I'm not so clear about the base current; is it always goes from emitter to base, through R2 to ground?

Correct, so in the opposite direction to that red arrow

@CÔNGNGUYỄNDUY To be saturated, the emitter must be close to the collector. Suppose so. The base only has access to ground. The collector is at ground. The emitter is very near ground. There cannot be much base-to-emitter voltage, whether reverse or forward. But likely reverse as the emitter is slightly positive and the base only has access to ground. Does not this sound like a falsification? Even if the base were tied directly to ground, wouldn't that make the bjt just a diode? Would that be saturated? Just asking some questions.

Perhaps this makes the difference clearer. In the first case, the transistor is operating in linear mode, or on the verge of it. Even when the base resistance is zero (Vce=-0.7 V). In the second case, the transistor operates in switching mode when the base current is high enough to saturate. In this case, the LED current is determined only by the supply voltage and 220 Ω, and will be independent of the base current, i.e. it will remain the same if, for example, the base resistance changes from 10k to 1k.
In the first case, the LED current depends on the supply voltage, the base current and 220 Ω.

